# Рассчитывание среднего значения и отклонения из рандомных данных из датафрейма

Tags: python, dataframe

Сделав рандомную выборку из таблицы, выссчитать среднее значение и отклонение с определенной колонны. Для этого процесса нужно написать функцию.
Получается я написал функцию, но оно с начала не функционирует.

```
def SampleMean(df, n, m):
    means = []
    for i in range(m):
        df_random = pd.DataFrame(columns=table.columns)
        num = np.random.randint(0,len(df))
        df_random.loc[num]=df.iloc[num]
    mean = df.random['G3'].mean()
    std = df.random['G3'].std()
    for j in range(m):
        xs = np.random.normal(mean, std, n)
        means.append(np.mean(xs))
    return means
```

Даю значеня и ругается *Invalid syntax* на n-ой аргументе.

```
def SampleMean(table, 10, 20)
```

Вот здесь после аргумента table, у меня ругается после компиляции.

**Почему ругается и где ошибка?**

Comment: а зачем вы вызываете функцию с `def`? с помощью def вы описываете функцию. вызывать ее надо просто по имени с аргументами: `SampleMean(table, 10, 20)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если всё так и написано, то прямо в def ставить 10 и 20 нельзя. Это же функция.
Добавьте main, вызывайте функцию оттуда.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не оставляйте такие "ответы". Оформляйте свои мысли как комментарии к вопросу. на такие ответы будет выставляться тэг "тревога" с последующим удалением ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, но только просьба ещё пояснить, что не так в моём ответе (я вижу, что вы в комментарий дали свой ответ). Мой ответ же отвечает на вопрос "Почему ругается и где ошибка?". И в правилах такое не запрещается прямо (ну, и комментировать я пока не могу - репутация мала, но это не важно).

Comment: Ответ - это развернутая рекомендация по решению вопроса, а не попытка, основанная на догадках. Мы с вами точно не знаем, помогут ли наши советы автору вопроса. Поэтому свой "ответ" я и оформил как комментарий.

Comment: Спасибо, ясно. Я правда, был уверен на 100%, что попытка ввести параметр подобным образом прямо в объявление функции добром не кончится:-), и автору это поможет, но идея понятна.